# Parsing Google Shopping Json Search Results

Tags: android, json, parsing

After a few weeks of trying numerous examples found here and it seems throughout the web, I'm stumped.  I can retrieve the desired search results from Google Shopping just fine:

```
{ "items": [  {   "product": {
"title": "The Doctor's BrushPicks Toothpicks 250 Pack",
"brand": "The Doctor's"  } } ] }
```

My problem is that I have the data sitting in a string, how do I extract the two values (title,brand) in order to use them elsewhere in the program?

Here is the class in question:
    public class HttpExample extends Activity {

```
TextView httpStuff;
DefaultHttpClient client;
JSONObject json;


final static String URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search..."; 

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.httpex);
    httpStuff = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHttp);
    client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    new Read().execute("items");

}

public JSONObject products(String upc)  throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException {
    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(URL);
    url.append(upc);

    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());
    HttpResponse r = client.execute(get);
    int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if (status == 200) {
        HttpEntity e = r.getEntity();
        String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
        JSONObject timeline = new JSONObject(data);
        return timeline;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(HttpExample.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        return null;
    }
}

public class Read extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            String upc = ExportMenuActivity.upc;
            json = products(upc);
            return json.getString(params[0]);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
    httpStuff.setText(result);
}
}
```

}

The output of httpStuff.setText(result):

```
[{"product":{"brand":"The Doctor's, "title":"The Doctor's..."}}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution that'd work on all versions of Android would look something like this:

```
JSONObject products = products(jsonStr);
JSONArray itemArray = products.getJSONArray("items");
for(int i=0; i<itemArray.length(); i++) {
  if(itemArray.isNull(i) == false) {
    JSONObject item = itemArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String title = item.getString("title");
    String brand = item.getString("brand");
  }
}
```

JsonReader is nice, but is only available in API 10 and up. So it might or might not work for you.

Comment: This looked promising since i'm using API 7, but the line: JSONObject products = products(jsonStr); causes an exception error with whatever value I plug in  like products(data), what am I missing at 3:21 am besides sleep.

Comment: Well, the function products() is where you make your GET call and hopefully receive your JSON. There's a number of things that could go wrong there, including a bad URL / wrong request params, no response or an error response from server, etc. Any of those things would trigger an exception. This is a separate issue from parsing the JSON though, which was the question I answered.

Comment: Thank's BlackRider, when you're banging your head against the wall, any step in the right direction is always appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `JsonReader` for reading the json string. Its very easy and well documented with very good sample.. [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html)